# What is the difference between "catch up with" and "follow up"?

Tags: north-american-english

I often hear "I'm going to catch up with him" or "I'm going to follow up with him" but I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

'Catch up with', while it can literally be a physical meeting, is informally used here to generally mean 'get or exchange news'. Friends who are meeting after a period of separation might catch up with each other. It may be used in more formal settings, like work, but is still usually seen as a less formal way of speaking.

'Follow up with', which is *not* used literally, is a more formal way of saying 'getting, giving or exchanging information' with another party. It's more often used in regards to business that one party has with another. In the US, a person is unlikely to 'follow up with' anything that's *personal* in regards to friend or acquaintance.

Answer (score 1):

To *catch up* is to match someone in some measure of progress.

> “Oh, you're watching *Awesome Series* too? Which season? I'd love to chat about it with you, but I don't want to risk spoilers, so I'll wait a bit for you to *catch up to me*.”

In the social sense, it means to share recent news, so that neither is “behind” in knowledge of the other's status.

> “I haven't seen you in years! We have so much to *catch up* on!”

To *follow up on* an action is to take the next step in a process initiated by the previous action.  To *follow up with* someone usually means to have a conversation about their progress on a project and what to do next.